# URL binary length

Tags: c#, url, c#-4.0

*Here i want to shorten my URL parameter binary which is around 3000 character and only 2000 is supported on the URL overall.*

*URL is below :-*

```
http://localhost:4659/SpaApi/InsertAttandance?userID=1&tokenkey=1&loginID=1&fingerprint=010001100100110001001000000001011001000000000110111110011010011001001000000011110010000000000110111111110010011001001000000011000101000000000111010000000011011001001000000010010001000000000111110100010101011001001000000010011001000000001000011100010010011001001000000001111010000000001000110010011111011001000100000000110001000000001001001000011101011001001000000010011001000000001001111000001101011001000100000001001110000000001010100110011110011001001000000010111101000000001010110100000000011001000100000001010000000000001011011000100000011001001000000010100101000000001011100010001001011001001000000010000100000000001100010100010101011001001000000010101010000000001100110011111100011001000100000001011010000000001101000000011100011001000100000000100111000000001101110000100000011001001000000011110111000000001101110111011001011001001000000010000100000000001110010100010101011001001000000010111100000000001110010111100001011001001000000010001011000000001111000000001001011001000100000011011110000000001111000011010111011001001000000010101111000000001111100011011100011001000100000011001100000000001111100011001011011001000100000011000011000000001111111001011000011001001000000001010010000000010000010010011111011001001000000010011100000000010000010011011111011001000100000000100000000000010001000010100011011001001000000010010111000000010001001010010000011001000100000010011111000000010001010110111110011001001000000010010101000000010001101110011100011001001000000010110111000000010001101101000011011001001000000000011001000000010001110100101010011001001000000001011011000000010010011110100011011001000100000001111011000000010010100010100100011001001000000010010000000000010010100010100101011001001000000010011011000000010010110110110000011001000000000000000000
```

*The paramter **fingerprint** holds the binary now i want it shortened i tried from byteArray which the java developer gave me but when i recieve the byte array as string after converting it to byteArray again it has changed the original binary format.*

Comment: Have you considered using `POST` to post those data, and then post the min the body of the request instead of the URL?

Comment: I'm scared to ask who thought it was a good idea to send the data as an *actual* binary string.

Comment: Hah, I didn't scroll out to see the actual data, as a sequence of 1's and 0's?????????????? At least use Base64 or Base85...

Comment: First convert it to binary data and *then* to `Base64` clearly :-) A simpler solution is to convert it to hex values (every 4 bits = 1 hex digit)

Comment: Actually Lasse this method your saying using Base64 will make use of Byte Array the java developer after converting will send me through URL in a string format but after conversion back to byte Array will not result in same binary in c#

Comment: @LukePark at least give a proper answer if you know. Otherwise this comment does not means. May be the developer is new and don't have an idea about this

Comment: @A.Goutam I'm unsure what you are saying.

Comment: Base64 encodes and decodes 1-to-1 bytes back and forth, same with Base85.

Comment: @rinki The correct thing to do here is, as recommended by Lasse, use base64.  If you've tried this and it didn't work then you have simply implemented it incorrectly.

Comment: That is, you encode a byte array into a Base64/85 string, and get a string safe to transport across text-based mediums, and when you decode this back to a byte array you get back the original bytes, with no loss or corruption.

Comment: Great idea @Lasse V. Karlsen convert byte array to Base64